# Was the system correct in failing me for this review audit?

Tags: support, review-audit

Please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/447772

I voted to close on the basis of "Off Topic", simply because no effort was shown toward a solution (which seems to be quite important on this site). However, the system then informed me that I was wrong to have closed it and I failed the audit.

Was I wrong? Have I (and many others, apparently) been too "harsh" in demanding that at least a modicum of thought or effort goes into a question before people are expected to give answers?

Comment: It is remarkable that the question you reviewed has 6 upvotes. To answer your question, the system determines whether you were "correct" or "incorrect" automatically based on, for example, whether the question is upvoted or downvoted/closed. Don't put too much stock or concern into the audit system if you're reviewing honestly. [Some people don't review honestly, which ruins the self-moderation of the site. The system does a pretty good job of catching them and preventing them from reviewing].

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: The one thing I have found in my time here (_maybe not in this instance_) is that sometimes the OP will place no effort in their original question, but upon being asked to do so they will provide what they have tried in the comments beneath the question, (which I have seen get deleted for being too long). After doing so their question amasses some upvotes, and then would most likely look quite confusing to someone in a review queue, or even someone who just stumbles upon the question, and infers that it is acceptable to ask their own question in the same manner which that one was

Comment: The question has now been closed as off-topic

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Thanks.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Then again, the proper course of action would be first to request an edit from OP, and upon no response, proactively add the information, to avoid the issue mentioned (and others).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Of course, yeah. Doesn't always seem to happen that way though.